# Version control without clutter

Tags: version-control, versioning

I personally don't like the .gitignore or .svn in my client copies. What is the best clutter-free server/client based versioning software that I would like to use for hobby projects for free. Because I would also like to archive my directory structure as is from the client (Here I assume I can manage this versioning nightmare.)

Clutter-free: Put versioning info on the server or on a separate directory that is configurable.

Comment: If there is no metadata in each directory, then how is a command-line version-control tool supposed to know what to do when presented with an arbitrary directory?

Comment: Keep that mapping in a separate directory outside the project and keep that directory's path in the environment variable? Otherwise I feel it pollutes my tree.

Comment: Sure, you could do that.  It would make it tricky to move a working copy, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Perforce](http://www.perforce.com) has no clutter.  It's free for up to 20 users now.

Answer (score 1):

TFS "11" has the concept of .tfignore files now as well.  TFS Express is completely free as well as the TFS Preview (http://tfspreview.com) at the moment.

You don't have to use .tfignore files though if you don't have a need for them...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, the new (>=1.7) TortoiseSVN does not have the .svn folders any more.  It is using a database instead, so you don't have "clutter" in your directories.

Comment: It is just a pet peeve, will give it a try. Both are right answers.